# Spark time series - how to parallelize code?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, time-series

I have a dataset with the following schema.

```
inputData.printSchema()
 |-- seriesKeys: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- targetSeries: double (nullable = true)
```

Using sparkts library, I would like to generate ARIMA forecasts in a distributed fashion for a large number of time series. Usually, I could approach this problem by using a TimeSeriesRDD [as described in this blog by Sandy Ryza](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/). According to my understanding, [TimeSeriesRDD](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/TimeSeriesRDD.scala) requires all series to have the same start and end date which is not the case for my dataset. So I need to write a code which can handle this situation.

Currently, my code is written in a way that everything is executed on the driver and not distributed across executors:

```
val seriesKeys: Array[Row] = inputData.select("seriesKeys").distinct().collect()

  val forecastArray : Array[Array[Double]] = seriesKeys.map(key => {
  val inputDataTemp : Dataset[mySchema] = inputData.where(s"seriesKeys ='$key'")
  val dfTS : DataFrame = inputDataTemp.select("targetSeries")
  val rddTS : RDD[Double] = dfTS.rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Double]("targetSeries"))
  val dvTS: Vector = Vectors.dense(rddTS.collect())
  val dvForecast: Vector = ARIMA.autoFit(dvTS, 5, 2, 5).forecast(dvTS, 12)
  dvForecast.toArray
})
```

How could I re-design the code to allow for parallel execution in oder to improve performance?

Comment: My spark version is 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a phone call pun, but don't call `collect`. You need to operate with the distributed abstractions like `RDD` and `Dataset/DataFrame`. The way you have it now `seriesKeys` isn't distributed because it is an `Array`.